# Zorin OS, can't boot from USB

Tags: windows, usb, uefi, zorin

I recently installed Zorin OS on my Lenovo Yoga 2. I completely got rid of Windows and am not dual booting. I am now trying to get back to Windows 10.

I created a Windows 10 USB drive, but I can't get the computer to boot from it. When I change the UEFI boot order, it still boots into Zorin, and when I go back to the UEFI, it has changed the boot order back.

I also created another Zorin USB drive, thinking I would boot from it, then format the Zorin partition so it would have to boot from USB. Same thing, it just won't boot from USB.

Is there a way to trigger booting from USB from within Zorin? If not, any ideas on how to get rid of Zorin some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall windows using an installation disk.

If you're using optical drive for installation set that as highest priority bootable device in `BIOS`.

In case of installation using `USB` drive configuration should be `BIOS` specific. Some allow explicitly selecting bootloader. Windows bootloader is named something like `win64.efi`. If your system allow chose that as bootloader. Otherwise in `BIOS` set the USB drive as highest priority hard drive to boot.

Reboot the system. Your system shall boot into windows installation.

Comment: This answer suggests courses of action that were indicated as tried already in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience in Zorion OS, but in my Gnu/Linux experience in general this issue is caused by the secure uefi. Here are my 3 cents:

1. Secure Boot is enabled in BIOS - try disabling it and boot again from USB
2. Try enabling legacy boot in BIOS - (if applicable to your machine) and boot again from USB
3. Verify if the usb image that has been flashed is bootable

Comment: Secure Boot didn't fix it, but for some reason legacy did! This is weird, because UEFI even recognized my USB as an EFI bootable drive, and the "legacy" list was empty. Can't argue with results, though.

Comment: EFI has always been weird from my perspective.

https://superuser.com/questions/801515/is-a-hybrid-linux-usb-stick-for-uefi-legacy-bios-possible

You can try to check if the flags mentioned there are set for this usb drive.