# How to boot into Fedora 27 on a Lenovo Yoga 310?

Tags: fedora, boot

Lenovo Yoga 310 is not booting into a Fedora Live USB.  Why could this be? I have checked the boot order and everything but the USB is not even displaying.  I've swapped USBs already and tried it with Ubuntu and still the same problem.

Girlfriend is sick of Windows because it is too slow.  I suspect it is just the awful Lenovo bloat so a reinstall would fix but she likes Gnome.

Comment: Do you have the an UEFI or SecureBoot option activated in the bios ? That's the most common reason for a Linux USB stick not booting.

Comment: Give more info, what you did, what happens?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable legacy boot capability from BIOS (if capable). This has done the trick for me many times.

See relevant post: [Zorin OS, can't boot from USB](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407649/zorin-os-cant-boot-from-usb/407658#407658)